# Facebook FQL query by Facebook ID

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new in Facebook development, I want to query facebook by Facebook ID for info like (likes, profile pictures e.t.c). 
I retrieve the URI ex. http://graph.facebook.com/1234567891 and i want to use 1234567891 to query Facebook.
I now how to implement the method and execute the query but I don't know how to start the query.

Does anyone now how to start the query??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it the query is "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid="123456789".
and for page "SELECT about FROM page where page_id=.........".